# Low temperature construction adhesive?

Tags: glue, pvc

My laziness has come home to roost.

I did some work over the summer that required me to rip out some old beadboard planking, which unfortunately destroyed most of the beadboard. After looking at the alternatives, I've purchased and cut some nice looking patterned PVC boards as replacement.

Only problem: you can't nail it, you need to glue it. And since I've managed to put off doing this work until December, it's 20-30 degrees here in sunny Albany, NY. I just looked at my tube of liquid nails, and it recommends not using it at temperatures less than 60 degrees F.

Could anyone suggest an alternative? I really don't want to leave this porch exposed for the season.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Liquid nails adhesive you have may be the basic interior grade. Take a look at the PL urethane adhesives, ie: PL200, PL400 etc. I don't have the specs in front of me, but I think you will find one that will perform OK in lower temps. Obviously, you may need to pick a nice sunny day, keep your new planking material inside and warm  until you are just ready to set it in place. What is the reason you can't use some 16 or 18 Ga finish nails or small diameter finish screws to secure the planks? If you have access under the planks there are some good screw type systems that will attach to joists and screw up from the bottom into your new decking.

Comment: Thanks, I found a liquid nails product that works down to 22F. I tried using nails, but found that about 30% of the PVC planks would crack. (probably due to temperature)

Comment: Ok,  when you are nailing PVC close to the edge, you got to use an air nailer, or pilot drill a 1/16 inch hole with hand bangers. A pilot hole and a super slim finish screw would work great. The head on a finish screw is only about 3/16" diameter and usually a torx or square head drive. I'd use both, adhesive and a screw/nail.